# How do I send application invite request programatically to list of Friends in Facebook iOS SDK 3.0?

Tags: facebook, user-interface

How do I send application invite request programatically to list of Friends in iOS SDK 3.0 ?

Normally on desktop UI we use FB.UI() but what we use for iOS using 3.0 FB SDK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/send-requests-using-ios-sdk/

Apprequests seem like they were not updated in 3.0 SDK. It still uses pretty much the same method as before, hence why you are required to import "deprecated headers".